# PHP - AJAX - JAVASCRIPT - $_FILES blank

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've seen lots of questions on this subject, but none of them seem to address my issue. It all seems pretty straight forward, but I just get a blank array, am I missing something really simple here?

Thanks.

Here is the `html / javascript` code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.js"></script>

   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" id="frmProduct" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="pdffile" name="pdffile" size="50" />                         
        <br />                         
        <input id="pdffileupload" type="submit" value="Upload" />      
        </form>

<script>
$('#pdffileupload').bind('click', function () 
{
   var files=document.getElementById('pdffile').files[0];
   var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append( "pdffile", files);

   $.ajax({
      url: '/info.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data)   { alert("YES"); },
      error: function(data){ alert("NO"); }
   });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

& PHP info.php

```
<?php 
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

Comment: please check upload file size. Try to upload less then 2mb file and check.

Comment: Set the AJAX `contentType` option to `multipart/form-data` or PHP won't know how to parse your request.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, the file size is 35k

Comment: Setting the contentType still produces the blank array.

Comment: Why has Java been tagged in this. Question doesn't involve Java.

Comment: @Anant Thank you, but I still get the same blank array, I'm using the chrome XHR inspector to see the result by the way.

Comment: @CrazyDino  I do apologise if I miss typed a tag as Java, rather than Javascript ! I'm assuming you don't have another more helpful reply ?

Comment: @AustinHarvey I came through from java tagged questions, so sorry.

Comment: @Anant Many thanks, that solved the problem.

Comment: @Anant more specifically the problem was the jquery script, I must have an outdated version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes needed (just check once by trying all my suggestions):-**

**1.In the same folder put both files (same working directory).**

**Code changes:-**

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery library like this -->

   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" id="frmProduct" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="pdffile" name="pdffile" size="50" />                         
        <br />                         
        <input id="pdffileupload" type="submit" value="Upload" />      
        </form>

<script>
$('#pdffileupload').bind('click', function () 
{
   var files=document.getElementById('pdffile').files[0];
   var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append( "pdffile", files);

   $.ajax({
      url: 'info.php', // remove /
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data)   { alert("YES"); },
      error: function(data){ alert("NO"); }
   });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

**And in php**

```
<?php 
print_r($_FILES); 
?>
```

**Note:- Check in your browser console (response tab).**

Comment: Many thanks again, the 2 problems were fixed.

1. using print_r($_FILES) in the php code
2. including the latest version of jquery 1.12.0 (my version was 1.4.4)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php var_dump($_FILES); ?>
```

Because the **var_dump** doesn't work with **$_FILES**.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply, unfortunately I just get this now 

Array ( )